# Is it possible to simulte the functionality of sql join in codeception, with the db module?

Tags: sql, join, codeception

I've been using php to query my db, and I am trying to transition to the codeception db module, but the documentation is sparse. As I mentioned in the title of the question, I am trying to get data from my tables with a sql join equivalent, but I can't figure it out from what I read in the documentation.

Comment: Please, try to explain what do you want to test first.

Comment: I need to select a product that fulfills a bunch of criteria, and I need to join 4 different tables.

Comment: You should use several checks, not one "big" test.
Use separate calls $I->seeInDatabase()

Comment: Also you could use ORM of your framework to write more high-level code in yout tests in terms of Product and other high-level entities, not in terms of tables. What framework do you use?

Comment: In my test, I select a valid for promotion product, its a small test. I think they use symfony, I test things :)